# Open source cluster SQL database in Linux

Tags: database, linux, open-source, rdbms, cluster-computing

Are there open source cluster relational database based on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, There Are a lot of open source cluster relational database based on Linux which Include MySQL Cluster, Postgres Cluster and a Newly Zvents Releases Open Source Cluster Database Based on Google (I m Not Sure If It is an Open source)

Comment: Does it cost? I am looking for some free open source cluster database actually